# Git cherry-pick from remote master to remote release branch

Tags: git

I merged a pull request to a remote branch (master). But the release branch was already created from master just moments before that - so my commit did not make it to release branch. Now, I have been told to cherry-pick my commit from remote master to remote release. Any pointers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cherry-pick my commit from remote master to remote release

Think remotely, work locally. Locally, `git fetch`. Now `git switch release` and `git cherry-pick <yourcommit>`. Push.